# Simple Math Problem: solving $ \ln(x) - \ln(1-x)=0$. What is wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, logarithms, roots

I have to solve :
$$0 = \ln(x) - \ln(1-x).$$

I did:

$0 = \ln(x) - \ln(1-x) \implies  e^0 = e^{\ln(x)} - e^{\ln(1-x)}  \implies 1 = x - (1-x) \implies 2 = 2x \implies x=1 $

The solution should be $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Where is my fault ? :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you take '$e$' of both sides you do indeed arrive at $$ e^0 = e^{ \ln x - \ln(1-x) } $$ because of the general property that $ a=b \implies e^a=e^b$. However, you then tried to use a false rule, that $e^{a-b} = e^{a} - e^{b} $. If you recall your index laws, you'll remember that the proper rule is $$ e^{a-b} = \frac{e^a}{e^b} .$$

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that if you take exponentials of both sides, you should get
$$e^0 = e^{\ln(x) - \ln(1-x)}.$$
But
$$e^{\ln(x) - \ln(1-x)} \neq e^{\ln(x)} - e^{\ln(1-x)}.$$
So your first step is incorrect.

Simplest thing is to first go from $0 = \ln(x) - \ln(1-x)$ to $\ln(1-x) = \ln(x)$ and *then* take the exponentials.

Alternatively, from
$$ e^0 = e^{\ln (x) - \ln(1-x)}$$
you can use the fact that $e^{a-b} = \frac{e^a}{e^b}$ to get
$$ 1 = \frac{e^{\ln(x)}}{e^{\ln(1-x)}},$$
and proceed from there.

P.S. Please don't use [homework] as the *only* tag in your post.